# Call a com object using a credential provider

Tags: windows, authentication, com, windows-authentication, credential-providers

I want to create an application to login to windows which would make use of a QR code, graphical password and Kinect motion password for my school project.

I've learnt that I would need to make use of credential providers. This is my first time using it and am extremely confused.

My question is: Is it possible to create an application with the above, and then have the credential provider call the application? And does the application I make have to be a com object?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news --- yes it's possible!
Bad news --- you have a lot of work to do ;)
As an advice, it's better if you keep your credential provider as simple as possible, and all work of user authentication via

> QR code, graphical password and Kinect motion password

will put in another app. So that credential provider will pass entered credentials to that app, and will receive back a result of authentication. The app will do the most hard work. This app should be a windows service, because it's always running regarding of are there any user sessions or not. Communication between app and credential provider can be done for example, by named pipes, or any other ipc mechanism.

For other questions:
Credential provider by itself is a COM.
To communicate with another apps, they aren't have to be a COM.
You can any app from credential provider as far as you have sufficient rights.

Answer (score 1):

The process does not have to be a service, you can start the exe from your COM object.

What you could do is regasm / codebase your COM object and then Latebind to it from the Credetial Provider in Initialize()

In GetSerialization() you would call the method in the COM object which starts the process(exe) and connect via a named pipe. It returns the values you need to the Credential Provider and you continue to Login.